# Finding minimum in Nedb datatable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nedb

I have following data structure in Nedb:

```
    ["UserId":"1446844665274","taskDone":"false","id":12,"_id":"1XURfx5uAZpgbh1i"]
    ["UserId":"1446844665274","taskDone":"false","id":10,"_id":"2I25xNAGTM7Iw2Af"]
    ["UserId":"1446844665274","taskDone":"false","id":3,"_id":"ESfi8ej5pbWBHV8o"]
    ["UserId":"1446844665274","taskDone":"false","id":9,"_id":"Etta7RLg2b09p9Bx"]
```

I am trying to filter for the row with minimum id value from the table. It will be really helpful if anybody can suggest how can i query NEDB to get the minimum id value?
I am using node.js along with nedb.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you [sort](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#sorting-and-paginating) it with the id ascending and get the first with limit

```
db.find({}).sort({ id: 1 }).limit(1).exec(function (err, docs) {
});
```